# Getting a file from the server via API call

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to download a file from my server using a API call in Angular 2, I am using the following call to make the request.

```
downloadFile(ID){
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'downloadFile/&ID='+ID).map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Although this call works to get data from the server, but I don't think it works for getting files, what do I need to change in this call for it to get the file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you `subscribe` to `downloadFile()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yes using the following:     `this.apiService.downloadFile(ID).subscribe(downloadFile =>{
    this.downloadFile= downloadFile;`

Comment: It seems like your URL format is incorrect. See if this helps call the api server `(this.baseUrl + 'downloadFile?ID=' + ID)

Comment: I was not passing the ID properly, and also getting rid of .map.. made it worked, I am subscribing to the api in a function and it opening a new window and going to the url for download is there a way to force the download while staying on the same page?